# User data in codeigniter session can't be accessed on multiple pages/views

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php

I am facing problems in codeigniter 2.x session class. I want to have userid in session for global access on my pages after user login

I have 2 views and 1 controller
one view one i had a login form when a user submits the form 
i validate it and create session user data by calling a method within controller as

```
function create_session($data) {        
        $mydata = array(
                   'userid'  => $data,
                   'role'     => $role,
                   'logged_in' => TRUE
               );

        $this->session->set_userdata($mydata);

        return;
    }
```

then my 2nd view is loaded 
and i have on that view

```
print_r($this->session->userdata);
```

and it print out the right results

but when i click on 1st view in navigation
i fond that

```
[userdata] =>
```

its empty
my session configuration is as

```
$config['encryption_key'] = 'askdfjowieuriomzx,mv';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'wana_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'wana_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

I have searched the forums, but i can’t solve this problem
please solve this issue or suggest an alternative method.

Comment: Weird, are you doing anything with the session after it's created?  Does this work on the most minimal example with no other functionality except creating and reading the session?

Comment: @Shomz I have not checked it. I am not doing anything with the session. Just setting the user data

Comment: Okay, and does it work if you use cookies instead of the database?

Comment: My first guess would be that the controller that is handling the navigation page creation doesn't have the session library loaded. Verify this first. If it doesn't you can load it there or, as Shomz mentioned further down, you can autoload it in the config > autoload.php file. I recommend doing this if you are using user data all over your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the reference to 'gmt' - in `config.php`

`$config['time_reference'] = 'gmt';` instead of `$config['time_reference'] = 'local';`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the comment I wrote you, make sure you load your session library on every page you need it, or you use autoload.

Answer (score 1):

if you set userdata you can access it from your main controller, assign it to a protected var(array) and anything that extends your main controller should have access to it.

```
class Main_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
protected $_session_data=array();

public function __construct()
{
   parent::__construct();

   if($this->session->userdata)
   {
      foreach($this->session->userdata as $k => $v)
      {
         $this->_session_data[$k] = $v;
      }
   }
}
}
```

some class extending your main controller

```
class someclass extends Main_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
  parent::__construct()
}

public function view1()
{
   $this->load->view('view1', array('session_data'=>$this->_session_data))
 }

 public function view2()
 {
    $this->load->view('view2', array('session_data'=>$this->_session_data))
 }
}
```

inside each view

```
var_dump($session_data['uid'])


foreach($session_data as $k){}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
```

This is my configuration, just a guess